# Is there a way to order the finished process to help the unfinished one in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Job: sample `N` ints in `{0, 1}`, assign "sampling `N_i` ints" to CPU `i`. `N = N_1 + ... + N_m`. Here is an implementation in Python, where `N = 16, m = 4; N_1, N_2, N_3, N_4 = 1, 2, 3, 10`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from random import sample

def func(Library, Timer, nums, pid, t0):
    # proc: pid, sample size: nums[pid]
    sub_Lib = []
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i = sample(range(2), 1)[0]
        Library.append(i)
        sub_Lib.append(i)
        # self job finished
        if len(sub_Lib) == nums[pid]:
            Timer[pid] = round(time.time()-t0, 2)
            break
        # ult job finished
        if len(Library) == sum(nums):
            Timer[pid] = round(time.time()-t0, 2)
            break
        pass
    pass

def run_process():
    Library = mp.Manager().list()
    Timer = mp.Manager().dict()
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 10]
    t0 = time.time()
    procs = []
    for pid, num in enumerate(nums):
        proc = mp.Process(target=func, args=(Library, Timer, nums, pid, t0))
        procs.append(proc)
        pass
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
        pass
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
        pass
    result = 'Ints: {}\nTime: {}'.format(Library, Timer)
    print(result)
    pass

def main():
    run_process()
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pass
```

Attention that the 4th process needs more time than the other 3. Is there a way to order the finished process to help the unfinished one? Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve with this? What do you mean by order? Do you expect the results to be in the same order as you have started the processes? How would that "help" the unfinished processes?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My request is when a process is over, it can join other processes' job, not just wait.